# is there a way to implement drag and drop functionality in older html

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am baffled with this questions. I want to believe that through some Javascript hacks or other standard means, the cool DnD [drag and drop]feature introduced in HTML5 can be implemented in older version.

has anyone attempted to achieve  this, what was the result  and how did they go about it?

I am creating a web app  that will handle lots of file uploads and I'm looking for ways to ease the upload process for my clients.

Any kind of help will be deeply appreciated!!

Comment: So you mean dragging files from your local computer, correct? Drag & drop within the HTML document has existed for several years now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a jquery plug-in for drag and drop.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/

http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/

Comment: Im pretty sure he is talking about the HTML5 DnD file upload functionality.

Comment: yea I'm talking about file upload with DnD and was hoping it could be achieved without HTML5

Answer (score 1):

You could use Flash.... or other browser plugins, otherwise nope.

Comment: Thats just too bad! Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're searching something for similar to the built-in functionality offered by WordPress in its Media Library. Historically, IE6 had some drag & drop events, such as ondragstart and other similar events. Unfortunately, IE's proprietary events were not supported by other browsers. To achieve what you need, you should consider using jQuery UI draggable and droppable objects. Run a search on Google for:

jquery drag and drop file upload

WordPress uses jQuery UI too.

Example: [JQuery File Upload Plugin](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/jquery-file-upload-plugin-with-drag-n-drop-support/)

I think he wants something cross-browser.

Comment: Im pretty sure he is talking about the HTML5 DnD file upload functionality.

Comment: He wants something cross-browser. ;-)

Comment: The DnD file upload I'm targeting will have to handle huge data transfer, I wonder if content-length header uses is limited to int